# Trim audio with iOS

Tags: cocoa-touch, audio, core-audio, trim

I want to implement a feature that lets the user trim an audio file (.caf) which he perviously recorded. The recording part already works, but how can i add a trimming feature similar to the one in the Voicememos app. Is there an api for the audio trimmer apple uses?
Any help would be great...

Comment: If anyone looking for answer in swift 4 check below link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54591972/10989334

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about using the AVFoundation? Import the audio file into an AVAsset (composition etc), then you can export it - setting preferred time + duration - to a file.

I wrote a stock function awhile ago that exports an asset to a file, you can also specify an audiomix. As below it exports all of the file, but you could add a NSTimeRange to exporter.timeRange and there you go. I haven't tested that though, but should work(?). Another alternative could be to adjust time ranges when creating the AVAsset + tracks. Of course the exporter only handles m4a (AAC). Sorry if this wasn't what you wanted.

```
-(void)exportAsset:(AVAsset*)asset toFile:(NSString*)filename overwrite:(BOOL)overwrite withMix:(AVAudioMix*)mix {
//NSArray* availablePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:asset];

AVAssetExportSession* exporter = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

if (exporter == nil) {
    DLog(@"Failed creating exporter!");
    return;
}

DLog(@"Created exporter! %@", exporter);

// Set output file type
DLog(@"Supported file types: %@", exporter.supportedFileTypes);
for (NSString* filetype in exporter.supportedFileTypes) {
    if ([filetype isEqualToString:AVFileTypeAppleM4A]) {
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
        break;
    }
}
if (exporter.outputFileType == nil) {
    DLog(@"Needed output file type not found? (%@)", AVFileTypeAppleM4A);
    return;
}

// Set outputURL
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* parentDir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/", [paths objectAtIndex:0]];

NSString* outPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", parentDir, filename];

NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:outPath]) {
    DLog(@"%@ already exists!", outPath);
    if (!overwrite) {
        DLog(@"Not overwriting, uh oh!");
        return;
    }
    else {
        // Overwrite
        DLog(@"Overwrite! (delete first)");
        NSError* error = nil;
        if (![manager removeItemAtPath:outPath error:&error]) {
            DLog(@"Failed removing %@, error: %@", outPath, error.description);
            return;
        }
        else {
            DLog(@"Removed %@", outPath);
        }
    }
}

NSURL* const outUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outPath];
exporter.outputURL = outUrl;
// Specify a time range in case only part of file should be exported
//exporter.timeRange =

if (mix != nil)
    exporter.audioMix = mix; // important

DLog(@"Starting export! (%@)", exporter.outputURL);
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void) {
    // Export ended for some reason. Check in status
    NSString* message;
    switch (exporter.status) {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
            message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Export failed. Error: %@", exporter.error.description];
            DLog(@"%@", message);
            [self showAlert:message];
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: {
            /*if (playfileWhenExportFinished) {
             DLog(@"playfileWhenExportFinished!");
             [self playfileAfterExport:exporter.outputURL];
             playfileWhenExportFinished = NO;
             }*/
            message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Export completed: %@", filename];
            DLog(@"%@", message);
            [self showAlert:message];
            break;
        }
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
            message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Export cancelled!"];
            DLog(@"%@", message);
            [self showAlert:message];
            break;
        default:
            DLog(@"Export unhandled status: %d", exporter.status);
            break;
    }       
}];
}
```

Comment: But this approach only allows the sound to be saved in the m4a-format, what if one like to trim an mp3 or a caf-file and keep the format?

Comment: Trim mp3 also work, ouput stored in m4a format
After 2 years, you still save my life :)

Answer (score 1):

The above answer of @Jonny is correct. Here's I'm adding the use of AudioMixer to add the Fade-in effect while audio trimming.

> Output: Audio asset trimmed to 20 seconds with a 10 second fade in.
>   The trim being set up in the code snippet takes place at the 30 second
>   mark of the asset and therefore the track duration should be at least
>   50 seconds.

```
- (BOOL)exportAssettoFilePath:(NSString *)filePath {


NSString *inputFilePath = <inputFilePath>;

NSURL *videoToTrimURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:inputFilePath];
AVAsset *avAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoToTrimURL];

// we need the audio asset to be at least 50 seconds long for this snippet
CMTime assetTime = [avAsset duration];
Float64 duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(assetTime);
if (duration < 50.0) return NO;

// get the first audio track
NSArray *tracks = [avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
if ([tracks count] == 0) return NO;

AVAssetTrack *track = [tracks objectAtIndex:0];

// create the export session
// no need for a retain here, the session will be retained by the
// completion handler since it is referenced there
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession
                                       exportSessionWithAsset:avAsset
                                       presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
if (nil == exportSession) return NO;

// create trim time range - 20 seconds starting from 30 seconds into the asset
CMTime startTime = CMTimeMake(30, 1);
CMTime stopTime = CMTimeMake(50, 1);
CMTimeRange exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime);

// create fade in time range - 10 seconds starting at the beginning of trimmed asset
CMTime startFadeInTime = startTime;
CMTime endFadeInTime = CMTimeMake(40, 1);
CMTimeRange fadeInTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startFadeInTime,
                                                        endFadeInTime);

// setup audio mix
AVMutableAudioMix *exportAudioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *exportAudioMixInputParameters =
[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:track];

[exportAudioMixInputParameters setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:0.0 toEndVolume:1.0
                                                  timeRange:fadeInTimeRange];
exportAudioMix.inputParameters = [NSArray
                                  arrayWithObject:exportAudioMixInputParameters];

// configure export session  output with all our parameters
exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]; // output path
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A; // output file type
exportSession.timeRange = exportTimeRange; // trim time range
//exportSession.audioMix = exportAudioMix; // fade in audio mix

// perform the export
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

    if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == exportSession.status) {
        NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");
    } else if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exportSession.status) {
        // a failure may happen because of an event out of your control
        // for example, an interruption like a phone call comming in
        // make sure and handle this case appropriately
        NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Export Session Status: %ld", (long)exportSession.status);
    }
}];

return YES;}
```

---

Thanks

For More Details :

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1730/_index.html