# Circular Buffer Audio Recording iOS: Possible?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

A client of mine wants to continually record audio and when he clicks submit he wants to submit the last 10 seconds only. So he wants a continual recording and only keeping the last x  seconds.

I would think this requires something like a circular buffer, but (as a somewhat newbie for iOS) it looks like `AVAudioRecorder` can only write to a file.

Are there any options for me to implement this?

Can anyone give a pointer?

Comment: Read the answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238219/trim-audio-with-ios Basically what you want to do is to export your recording as an asset and then using AVExportSession trim it to the last 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the Audio Queue Services.  This will allow you isolate certain parts of the buffer.  Here is the guide to it: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQRecord/RecordingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH4-SW1

Comment: This works great, I do have some trouble with saving the buffers when it is m4a, but the concept works great!