# iOS, AVPlayer - looping MP3 segment

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, avfoundation, avplayer

I am trying to loop a segment of an MP3 loaded from the users iPod library. By segment I mean, I don't want to loop the entire MP3 but only a section of it.

So say the MP3 is 4 minutes long, I have defined startTime, and endTime.

When the play button is hit, I seek the player to startTime and begin play.

I'm also subscribed to the event listener [AVPlayer addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:...] to be notified when my endTime has hit. At which point, I seek back to startTime and play.

** However, this does not provide a seamless loop - there is a split second where the sound stops before playing at startTime again.. My application is music making software, so it is important that the loop is perfect. Please help!

Comment: At a glance I can suggest: you may cut the exact part from the audio file and simply loop the whole file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was considering this, although I don't know if Apple's policy allows for saving MP3 files from their iPod library. Will definitely explore this more though.

Comment: @AndyHin it does. There's te AVAssetWriter class which does exactly that.

Comment: To understand how MP3 works, I would read this link. Helps you understand why you get the silent parts: http://www.compuphase.com/mp3/mp3loops.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a Technical Q&A called [Exporting a Trimmed Audio Asset](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1730/_index.html).

Also, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698787/ios-audio-trimming), which deals with trimming an AVAsset audio file.