# cut an audio from specific time to end in ios

Tags: ios, audio, trim, avaudiorecorder

I am recording an audio in in AVAudioRecorder but its long audio, i want to cut it from specific time to the end.

Eg.

total length = 5 minutes.
So new file should start from 3 minutes to the end and delete the old file.

I searched online and was able to slice it but then sample rate goes to 44100 from 16000, i want to keep the same sample rate. I followed this question. [iOS Audio Trimming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698787/ios-audio-trimming)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Include the code that caused the sample-rate change, please.

Comment: Please see in my question, i have referenced one question.

Comment: There are two answers there, nevermind that someone might add more.

Comment: Hello @Paragon , have you find the solution. I am facing the same problem.