# Save Audio from Online Streaming Audio iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to make an app which can record `online streaming audio` like `Radio` and if person want they can `save` that `audio` in `Local Document Directory` to listen in future.

Comment: [link](http://vombat.tumblr.com/post/86294492874/caching-audio-streamed-using-avplayer)       https://github.com/calm/PersistentStreamPlayer                  https://rymc.io/2014/01/08/recording-live-audio-streams-on-ios/

Comment: Well, and what exactly is your problem with that?

Comment: they only play audio not record

Comment: Did you try hugging into `connection:didRecevieData:` and store it locally? Or in `connectionDidFinishLoading:` where the cached data is already stored in files and store the full file additionally instead of the currently cached part only?

Comment: i am trying these methods and give you feedback and thxx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131798/discussion-between-gurinder-batth-and-hermann-klecker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an API in iOS to do this.

You can save an audio stream (provided it is a completed file), but live streams are not as easy because they technically have no end. So the issue is they download forever.

Livesteams also can't be 'recorded' while playing either, due to the design of the iOS audio API.

You could however develop a library which allows you to "tap into the data stream" which is being downloaded and save it on demand. This is not a trivial task, but it can be done.

[Saving an audio file from the web - SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453550/objective-c-ios-save-audio-stream-to-file)