# How to allow UIScrollView to scroll below content offset 0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate, contentoffset

I'm using `UIScrollView` to create recording timeline just like Voice Memo app. This is horizontal `scrollview's` frame at the beginning. I use `CAShapeLayer` to draw bars.

```
 scrlViewBars.frame = CGRectMake(0, scrlViewBars.frame.origin.y, SCREEN_WIDTH, 100);
    ....
 [shapeLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, barWidth, barHeight) cornerRadius:2] CGPath]];
 [scrlViewBars.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

Recording starts and draws wave bars from beginning i.e wave bars are created from zero X position of `UIScrollView`. When bars will reach to the half of the screen, I start moving `UIScrollView` back by giving `contentSize` and `contentOffset`. So bars then will remain in centre after that just like Voice Memo app.

Everything works great except proper `UIScrollView` timeline. If the recording is small, `contentSize` will not be larger than screen width. So is it possible to `UIScrollView` to go below 0 `contentOffSet`? Because after recording is stopped, user can scroll timeline and starting content of recording should go till centre of the screen because there is a scrub bar at the centre which will not move and shows current recording time.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the contentInset property to have some inset from left, that should do the trick.

```
self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width/2, 0, 0);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for answering. I already tried it. The problem is that at beginning bars will be created from zeroth position. scroll will not move until bars reach at half screen.Then I'm moving scroll view. so If record is too small. I face problems here.

Comment: Then you can try using min contentSize as the scrollView's width. With that done even if your waves are small your contentInset will do the magic.

Comment: thanks for the idea. I will work on it and let you know

Comment: I use AVAudioRecorder to record audio. What should be recommended now for audio cropping anywhere from timeline and record over from there? So I want cropping and merging. Please reply as soon as possible

Comment: You can use AVAssetExportSession please refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698787/ios-audio-trimming

Comment: done it already using AVAssetExportSession  and AVMutableComposition. Thanks :)