# AVAudioRecorder setting recording start time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudiorecorder

I am using AVAudioRecorder for recording sound in my ios app. I want that if user moves the UISlider object to 2 seconds and press Record button then after saving the recording file and playing it, user should hear the recording after a pause of 2 seconds. How can I achieve this functionality? Can anyone please help?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can **add  2 second silence** (please consider slider value is 2) to your  Audio file starting section

To do this please go through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252032/adding-silence-to-the-end-of-a-recorded-audio-file)

The below links also may help you to achieve the goal.

[avaudioplayer-append-recording-to-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649918/avaudiorecorder-avaudioplayer-append-recording-to-file)

[trim-audio-with-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238219/trim-audio-with-ios)

Comment: Thanks Ramshad, but how would I create this silent audio? The link you provided asks to pause the audio, but pausing an audio will not add that gap. It will just stop the recording at that time for the time being. Right?