# How to crop audio in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, audio-recording, avplayer

I'm wondering how can I crop some part of voice and audio and make them together in single file using Objective-C code.

Should I use C++ library?

Want to convert avaudiorecorder to data and choose some parts.

Comment: look at these links may help you [Trim audio with iOS][1]


[iOS Audio Trimming][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238219/trim-audio-with-ios
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698787/ios-audio-trimming

Comment: Open the files, extract the data, find what you want, combine, construct new file header, write file.  Simple.

Comment: @HotLicks can you give me a link?

Comment: The file formats are on the web, if you Google for them.  It's a SMOP.